# Search a file in sub folders

Tags: batch-file

When i try to search the zip file in sub-folders of "Input_Files", the command is not running after "\172.24.191.117\data1\NEW-ENDORSEMENTS\Backlog_checked\%J%\CLIENT-SUPPLIED\Backlog". I think the space is problem to get the path. Kindly check and clear.

```
@echo off
echo.
set /p J=Enter Journal ID : 
set /p A=Enter Article ID : 
set "BaseDir=\\172.24.191.117\data1\NEW-ENDORSEMENTS\Backlog_checked\%J%\CLIENT-SUPPLIED\Backlog Transfer\Non EV articles\%J%%A%"
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('
  Dir /B/S/A-D "%BaseDir%\*.zip" ^| Findstr /I "\\Input_Files\\[^\\]*\.zip$"
') Do start %%A
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `start %%A` by `start "" "%%A"`.

**DIR** outputs the found file matching the pattern with full qualified file name (file path + file name + file extension) never enclosed in double quotes. So it is necessary to reference the file with embedding it in double quotes as done here with `"%%A"`.

The first double quoted string is interpreted by command **START** as optional title. For that reason a title must be explicitly specified to avoid interpreting the full qualified file name in `"` as title string. As the started application for opening the *.zip file is most likely a GUI application, an empty title string can be used with `""` because no command process with a console window is opened in this case.